# joining/searching 3 tables

Tags: sql, left-join

I have 3 tables

```
order (customerID, productID)
product (productID, prodName, classID)
classification (classID, className)
```

I need to get prodName and className where customerID=5555

```
SELECT prodName FROM product AND className FROM classification
LEFT JOIN order
WHERE order.customerID=12345
```

It's not working, I think I may be joining the wrong table or something. What's wrong? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Is that the actual query you are using?

Comment: You may want to look into some SQL tutorials. This would be the simplest example of a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify what field the join is on, like this:

```
SELECT prodName FROM product AND className 
FROM classification
LEFT JOIN order
ON classification.productID = order.productID
WHERE order.customerID=12345
```

Comment: I'm a little concerned that this syntax is still off.  I'm mainly looking at the `AND between product and classname` and also the second `FROM` after className.  I don't think this will run; tried it in MS SQL 2014; can you confirm/deny @The 42nd Doctor?

Comment: I use SQL Sever 2008, so I can't be sure about SQL 2014. It would probably be easier to use 
`SELECT product.prodName, classification.className FROM classification
LEFT JOIN order
ON classification.productID = order.productID
WHERE order.customerID=12345`
since that's the more common syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is a little off;

```
SELECT
   prodName
FROM
   product
   ,classification LEFT JOIN order ON(classification.classID = order.classID)
WHERE
   order.customerID = 12345
   and order.productID = product.productID
```

That will return your Prod Name.  Have to be honest, I'm not sure why you're doing a left join here; you never do anything with it.  LEFT JOIN will return you all of the records from Classification and ONLY the matching records from Order. The below would do the same thing without the pointless LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT
    prodName
FROM
    product
    ,classification
    ,order
WHERE
    order.customerID = 12345
    AND order.classID = classification.classID
    AND order.productID = product.productID
```

In fact, the only reason I see for even joining the Classification table is to ensure that the order has a valid classification, which you should be verifying on the record's creation anyways.  You might want to rethink what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

See [this tutorial on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).  Your SQL syntax is incorrect.  It should look more like:

```
SELECT prodName, className
FROM product
LEFT JOIN order ON order.productID = product.productID
WHERE order.customerID = 12345
```